# Multiplicity of a function

Tags: functions

I am slightly unsure about how to calculate the multiplicity of a function but I was wondering if the multiplicity of $(x^3 - 2)$ is $3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiplicity of a factor of a polynomial is the number of times the factor divides the polynomial. For example, in the polynomial $(x-3)^2(x^2-3)$, the factor $x-3$ has multiplicity $2$ and the factor $x^2-3$ has multiplicity $1$. In your example, the multiplicity of $x^3-2$ is *not* $3$ because you're not cubing the entire factor: it *would* be $3$ if you had $(x-2)^3$ instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So my function has multiplicity one then? @user134824

Comment: Sound good to me.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I mean I think you're 100% right but I was getting confused about when x=1.25992105 i.e. the cubed root of 2. Would it not have a multiplicity of 3?

Comment: It would have multiplicity $3$ if it were $(x-\sqrt[3]{2})^3)$.